# Mysql, sorting by field count

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

i have a table called purchased_albums

```
id  album_id    member_id   date
4      8              7     2013-12-24 08:17:54
5      9              7     2013-12-29 11:03:35
6      8              10    2013-12-24 08:17:54
```

im trying to sort it out by most purchased albums. that is, it should count the most repeated album_id and sort it out based on that. my query keeps returning null.

```
$q="SELECT COUNT(album_id) as tot,album_id,date  FROM purchased_albums ORDER BY tot DESC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(album_id) as tot,album_id,date  
FROM 
    purchased_albums 
GROUP BY album_id
ORDER BY tot DESC";
```

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this code may be you will find your exact requirement.........

```
  $q="SELECT COUNT(album_id) as tot,album_id,date FROM purchased_albums GROUP BY album_id ORDER BY album_id DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join to get the count per album, then order by the resulting quantity:

```
SELECT pa.*
FROM purchased_albums pa
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) qty_purchased, album_id
    FROM purchased_albums
    GROUP BY album_id
) c ON pa.album_id = c.album_id
ORDER BY c.qty_purchased DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Might something like this help you?

```
SELECT `album_id`, `date`, COUNT(*) `purchases`
FROM `purchased_albums`
GROUP BY `album_id`
ORDER BY `purchases` DESC
```

To pick out albums, that are purchased more then e.g. 3 times, use HAVING

```
SELECT `album_id`, `date`, COUNT(*) `purchases`
FROM `purchased_albums`
GROUP BY `album_id`
HAVING `purchases` > 3
ORDER BY `purchases` DESC
```